# Gradient of $x \mapsto (w^tx+b)^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

I have a non-zero column vector w $\in \mathbb{R^2}$ and a scalar b $\in \mathbb{R}$, so it's a function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ with this definition: $f(x) = (w^tx + b)^2$, where $x$ is a column vector $\in \mathbb{R}$. Now I want to calculate the gradient of f at x $\nabla_xf(x)$. This is what I have tried:

$$ f(x) = (w^tx+b)^2 = (w^tx)^2 + 2(w^txb) + b^2$$
$$ \nabla_x f(x) = 2(w^tx) + 2(w^tb)$$
$$ \nabla_x f(x) = 2w^t (x + b) $$

I'm not sure if this is correct since $w$ is a column vector so I think a component like $ w^tw $ could be missing. Please, could you point out what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed missing one term. I will try to post it as a question as soon as possible.

Comment: No actually that is correct. Yet if you want to completely justify your answer write : $$ f(x+h) = (w^t(x+h)+b)^2$$ then $$f(x+h)=(w^t(x+h))^2+b^2+2w^t(x+h)$$ then continue and isolate the linear term in $h$. That gives you your differential then you gradient.

Comment: Hello @VanBaffo, great, your answer will be helpful! My hunch is that the missing term allows the square operation (hence the matrix multiplication would require the transposed x not transposed operation) but I'm not sure. Please, your help will be appreciated

Comment: @EDX, thanks, just a question, the last term should be $2w^t(x+h)b$, isn't it?

Comment: @Alexis yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt is the following, by using differentials:

\begin{align}
f(x+ dx)&= (w^t(x+dx)+b)^2\\
&= (w^tx)^2 + (w^tdx)^2 +b^2 + 2 (w^txw^t)dx + 2 w^txb + 2 bw^tdx \\
&= (w^tx + b)^2 +   2(w^txw^t)dx + 2 bw^tdx + \mathcal{O}(dx^t dx) \\
& \simeq f(x) + \nabla_xf(x)^t  dx
\end{align}

So the linear term in the increment $dx$ is your gradient (tranposed), in this case:

\begin{align}
\nabla_xf(x)= 2(x^t w + b)w
\end{align}

Comment: Hello @VanBaffo, I appreciate the answer, just a question, the final term in third row is an $O(dx^tdx)$ and I want to be sure if that O was a typo or a special notation

Comment: It is the big O notation, meaning that they "vanish" and you can simply not consider, informally.

Answer (score 0):

As @VanBaffo answered this question, this is my attempt to validate the answer provided:

We can apply the chain rule which states $h'(x)=f'(g(x)).g'(x)$. Now, for $f(x) = (w^tx + b)^2$ we consider $u$ as $(w^tx + b)$, so:
$$f'(u) = 2u = 2(w^tx + b)$$ and the derivative of u with respect to x is $w$. So the result is
$$2(w^tx + b)w$$