# Gradient of $ \left( \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} \right)^2 - 2\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}$ w.r.t $\mathbf{w}$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

That's it. So far I've tried the following but I'm not certain if I'm allowed to do that.
\begin{align}
\frac{d\left( \left( \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} \right)^2 - 2\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} \right)}{d\mathbf{w}} &= \frac{d\left( \left( \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} \right)^2 - 2\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} \right)}{d(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x})}\cdot \frac{d(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x})}{d\mathbf{w}} \\
&= \left(2\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} - 2\right) \cdot \mathbf{x} \quad \text{(assuming Denominator layout)}
\end{align}
My question is, can I use the chain rule to go from a derivative w.r.t to a vector to a derivative w.r.t to a scalar size? (i.e $\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}$)

Comment: You might find useful this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4621027/263664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer checks out. The proper way would have been to do it componentwise in which case you get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\left((w^Tx)^2-2w^Tx)\right)}{dw_i} = (2w^Tx-2)x_i 
\end{align*}
and thus the gradient is
\begin{align*}
\nabla_w\left((w^Tx)^2-2w^Tx)\right) = (2w^Tx-2)x
\end{align*}
as you stated correctly.